# can't import torchaudio in a kaggle notebook

Tags: python, pytorch, kaggle, torchaudio

I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'torchaudio._internal.module_utils' has no attribute 'requires_sox'
```

while importing `torchaudio`

### To Reproduce

I'm using a `kaggle notebook`

just executed these lines:

```py
!pip install --upgrade torch
!pip install --upgrade torchaudio
import torchaudio
```

### Environment

- PyTorch version: 1.9.0+cu102
- Is debug build: False
- CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.2
- ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (x86_64)
- GCC version: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
- Clang version: Could not collect
- CMake version: version 3.10.2
- Libc version: glibc-2.10
- Python version: 3.7.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 19 2021, 16:07:37)  [GCC 9.3.0] (64-bit runtime)
- Python platform: Linux-5.4.120+-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
- Is CUDA available: True
- CUDA runtime version: 11.0.221
- GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB
- Nvidia driver version: 450.119.04
- cuDNN version: Probably one of the following:
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.8.0.4
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.0.4
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.0.4
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.0.4
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.0.4
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.0.4
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.0.4
  HIP runtime version: N/A
  MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this using google colab. Maybe it's a problem with your IDE?

Comment: yeah, it works fine in colab. for some reason tho, it doesn't work in _kaggle_. I'm not using an IDE, kaggle has their own notbooks

Comment: error shows `'requires_sox'` and there is C/C++ program `sox` to work with audio in command line. So it may need to install it. On local Linux I would use `apt install sox` but I don't know if it will work in `Kaggle`. See home page for [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: the error was because while I was playing with the notebook, I imported torchaudio _before_ upgrading it. And for some reason, that messed things up (i.e. trying to import torchaudio again caused the above error). I tried again this morning with a fresh session and it worked! thank you guys so much for trying to help me.